# How to interate over two or more vectors or tuples in julia?

Tags: julia

Can we iterate over two or more vectors or tuples in julia?

```
julia> c=Tuple(x for x in a, b)
```

The above code does not work but shows what i want to do. I need to iterate over both a and b one after other.

Suppose,

```
julia> a=(1,2)

julia> b=(3,4)
```

and I want c to be:

```
julia> c=(1,2,3,4)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Very short version:

julia> a=(1,2)

julia> b=(3,4)

julia> c = (a..., b...)

(1, 2, 3, 4)

Answer (score 3):

Use:

```
julia> c = Tuple(Iterators.flatten((a, b)))
(1, 2, 3, 4)
```

to get a `Tuple` as you requested. But if you are OK with a lazy iterator then just `Iterators.flatten((a, b))` is enough.